# php preg regex - group of whitspaces without linebreak in multiline mode

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Hello I am trying to split some input by line, and use trim() on each line. But I would like to do it without using trim, just with regex.

The issue I am having with this, is that whitspaces at the end of the line are not trimmed away. I guess my group [^$\s] whitespaces but no linebreak does not work.

So the question is, how to solve my problem, and how to define a group in preg regex, which explicitly says ignore line breaks? At the moment I am thinking my approach is still wrong. The problem is, if I write \s* instead of this weird group. .+ eats all. If I write .+? I do not get strings which include spaces back complete.

```
preg_match_all("/^\s*+(.+)[^$\s]*+$/m", $_POST['input'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
```

Comment: What a wonder. This way I solved it.
/^\s*+(.+?)\s*$/m

Comment: Yeah, just make `.+?` less greedy. But why did you want to avoid trim?

Comment: I wanted to trim the lines, otherwise it would have been too easy anyways.

Comment: One difference from trim is that you skip whitespace-only lines completely, trim would give you empty strings instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm usually all for using regular expressions. But the `trim` approach would be simpler here. And I assume you avoided it because it usually requires an extra loop. But in this instance you could compact it to:

```
 $lines = array_map("trim", explode("\n", $_POST["input"]));
 // quite a handy utility function, so just wanted to note that here
```

But as alternative to your found solution, you could have alternatively used:

```
preg_split('/((?!\n)\p{Z})*\n((?!\n)\p{Z})*/u', "...\n...");
```

A bit hackish now. Swapped out the `^$` just for `\n`, and used assertions to exclude newlines elsewhere. But the `\p{Z}` is a nice alternative to catch all Unicode space character variations, including NBSP and other ninja placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/\s*(.*\S)/", $_POST['input'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
```

You need something to eat leading whitespace before your capture group, including whole lines. `\s*` does that. You don't need to force it to start at the beginning of a line, you're not saving it anyway -- its only purpose is to match up to just before a non-whitespace character.

So now you know that you're looking at non-whitespace, and need to capture up to the last non-whitespace on the same line. Since `.` won't match newline, `.*\S` does just that.

One difference from your version is that the initial `\s*` of the next match gets to eat the trailing whitespace on the line you just matched. Since we no longer care about line endings, the `/m` modifier is no longer necessary.

You could make the first star possessive (`\s*+`); that won't change what it matches, but it will make it fail marginally faster at the end of the file if there's a long empty tail.